# How to disable touch events for the top view so that it lets touch events to pass through to the underlying view?

Tags: android, xml

I am an android beginner and have looked for a solution to this problem, but apparently couldn't find it
I have a Google Map fragment and a canvas taking up the same space in XML. A Circle is drawn on the canvas. But with the current setup, canvas doesn't let touch events pass through to the map. I want a transparent canvas with a circle on top of Map view in a way so that touch events are disabled for canvas but map receives touch events. Please note that using Google Map's Circle class as an alternative to canvas is not an option.
Here is my XML. [enter image description here][1]

```
<FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <fragment 
                  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:id="@+id/map"
                        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"

                        />

                    <com.example.murtaza.bettertracker.ui.CircleCanvasClass
                        android:id="@+id/circleView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:visibility="visible" />
            />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: You can set the onTouchListener on top view and return false.

Answer (score 0):

Set touch listener on the top view

```
topview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener{ 
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e){ 
    return false; 
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for response. Doing what you suggested still doesn't let touch events pass through to the underlying view.

Comment: It works for button underlying a button etc but not for mapFragment underlying  canvas. I think it has something to do with canvas subclassing the View class and i need to override some View method to enable this behavior.

Comment: try setting clickable false i am not sure if this will work or not

Comment: Like i said, setting clickable to false works for button underlying a button but not for mapFragment underlying a canvas.